# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'aes_decrypt'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, encryption

I am trying to move our encryption from Code to the database to speed things up.  When I attempt to decrypt the information using this select statement I get an incorrect parameter count error.

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(u.strFirstName,'usa2010') FROM EncryptingTest.tblUser u;
```

I've looked at the documentation and this should work.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong??

EDIT
I have tried Restarting the MySQL Server to no avail.  The server Version is 5.6.22

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? [The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt) implies this should work.

Comment: Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'aes_decrypt'  - This is the error i receive

Comment: Did you read up on the Block Cypher Mode in the link I provided?

Comment: I did, and that was the issue.  What is weird is that I was able to do it before I updated....  Marking your answer as correct

Comment: I had a good feeling it was thats why i posted the link. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example you provided it seems ok. Can you see about casting it first?

```
 SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(u.strFirstName,'usa2010') AS CHAR(50)) FROM EncryptingTest.tblUser u;
```

Please check this link it has some great resources on the issue your facing...

http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2014/03/27/mysql-5-6-17-now-with-better-encryption/

**EDIT** - The actual fix

Using AES_ENCRYPT() or AES_DECRYPT() with block_encryption_mode set to a block cipher other than ECB will produce an error if the IV is not provided:

```
 mysql> SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

```
 mysql> SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('test', 'key'));
```

ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'aes_encrypt'
     mysql> SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('test', 'key', RANDOM_BYTES(16)));
+---------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('test', 'key', RANDOM_BYTES(16))) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2EFBA8708925C1DF8B661E57938FAE5E                  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
Note that the IV isn’t itself stored in the resulting encrypted output – it’s an artifact that you’ll have to track separately to get the decrypted values back:

```
 mysql> SET @iv = RANDOM_BYTES(16);
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

```
 mysql> SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('test', 'key', @iv));
```

+--------------------------------------+
| HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('test', 'key', @iv)) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 650CE9E699ECA922E09E80CEBE51BFC7     |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```
 mysql> SELECT AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX('650CE9E699ECA922E09E80CEBE51BFC7'), 'key', @iv);
```

+--------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
 AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX('650CE9E699ECA922E09E80CEBE51BFC7'), 'key', @iv) |
```

+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I receive the same error message.... I have attempted stopping and restarting the MySQL server as well

Comment: Glad this helped, but it doesn't make it clear to the (casual) reader to how the problem was actually solved. Was it the cast?

Comment: No it wasnt, it was the cypher mode. See edit as it pertains his issue he was facing which caused it. Thanks for the input.